# HTOP shows massive memory usage but proceslist shows otherwise

Tags: ubuntu, memory, performance, htop

I'm running htop on my `Ubuntu 16.04LTS` server to monitor my `CPU` and `RAM` usage. I'm aware of the color indications used by htop as outlined below:

[image: htop default color usage]

So, when I look at my `htop`-overview, it shows me the following:
[image: htop overview]

However, this seems rather unclear to me. `htop` shows a memory usage of almost 100% (some `cached memory`, but mainly `used RAM`). However, when I look at the main processes (childs are hidden), I won't even come close to 50% `RAM` usage (16.1% + 11.6% + 2.7%).

So, this confuses me a bit and I would like to know why htop shows me a almost fully used `RAM`-bar?

Important to note is that, looking at the `meminfo` page, I see the following overview, indicating a lot of cached RAM in contradiction to what htop is showing me?

[image: meminfo]

So, I would actually expect a `RAM-usage` bar in htop with a lot more yellow/orange? Though, it consists of green for approximately 85%?

Could it perhaps be that there are many (very short running) processes, which require a lot of RAM but suspend to quickly for htop to show them?

**EDIT**
Another picture of htop (with processes using more memory) and meminfo together
[image: htop and meminfo together]

Comment: Are you perhaps using ZFS?

Comment: @DanielB no, not that I'm aware of. Where can I check this?

Comment: You’d know. On second thought, the memory usage pattern doesn’t match anyway. You have a lot of shared memory, also note how your cached memory is not considered “available”.

Comment: @DanielB, indeed. However, why is htop now showing it in the RAM-bar as orange/yellow since it is cached? Besides, my memory usage doesn't seem to look bad (server response is fast and good). Though, when based on htop, I would conclude that my server is used at almost 100% RAM capacity? I don't understand the relation between both

Comment: Because it is not cached in the sense of being available for reuse. Something is still using this memory.

Comment: @DanielB, hmm alright. How can I figure out which processes are eating the memory? So, to clarify: a large part of my memory is cached, but not free for reuse? I have also uploaded another image where you can see htop and meminfo next to each other. meminfo tells me I have like 265MB of memory available and 116MB free?